# Selecting item in a virtualized XAML ListView throws an StackOverflow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, virtual

I have this XAML form with a virtualized ListView to show a grid:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfVirtualList.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="lvStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding}"/>
        <Setter Property="ListView.View">
            <Setter.Value>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Cups" Width="200">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CUPS}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="MeterId" Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MeterID}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Matricula" Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MatriculaCT}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLoading}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ListView.Cursor" Value="Wait"/>
                <Setter Property="ListView.Background" Value="LightGray"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="lv" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Style="{DynamicResource lvStyle}" SelectionChanged="lv_SelectionChanged" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And when I select an item everything works OK...
[image: Selection]

But when I select a second item the system throws an StackOverflow... and I don't know why.

I have breakpoints in all the virtual list methods, but no one of them are called when I click on the second item.

I have a breakpoint in SelectionChanged event, and isn't called either.

```
    //CUPS is the id
    private void lv_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
            Debug.WriteLine("selected: "+((ItemClass)e.RemovedItems[0]).CUPS);
        if(e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
            Debug.WriteLine("unselected: " + ((ItemClass)e.AddedItems[0]).CUPS);
    }
```

I fixed it controlling the GotFocus event and unselecting all... but this is not the way to solve this.

```
    private void lv_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lv.UnselectAll();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post for your `lv_SelectionChanged` mehtod?

Comment: @sthotakura I just added the method...

Comment: Show us your ViewModel and tell us are you doing something with your ListView in code behind or somewhere else? Is this all you got?

Comment: @devhedgehog It's a usual virtual listview that implements IList<T> and IList

Comment: @rasputino Please if you wish us to provide you precise help you will have to give us all your code so we can run it without making up our own things. We need exactly your code to exactly reproduce the issue and solve it. I would love to help you out but by telling me that you have a usual virtual listview that implements IList is not a great help. :) Code will resolve any question. Therefore always post code. Feel free to upload your issue on github.com and post the link here for us.